# Want to migrate a java project build automation from Ant to Maven and this project have multiple modules and final result should be an ear

Tags: maven, ant

Want to migrate a Java project build automation from Ant to Maven and this project have multiple modules and final result should be an ear.

Already having build.xml which we  need to call from maven plugin

Comment: First if you migrate than don't call build.xml from Maven it does not make sense..either migrate or not but not half...having an ear which contains several modules like ejb, jar's etc. is a typical setup for a multi module build......

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,but it not solves my issue could you please provide a specific solution.Project contains only two modules one module final product is war and other generating ear with some meta data so finally I need to bind that war into this ear with meta data.If you can give me some concrete ans would make my life easy.

Comment: I should provide a solution for you? Sorry but I don't do your job...what have you tried so far? What are the issues you have faced with? ...etc. take a deeper look into the idea behind SO....

Comment: As suggested by @khmarbaise, post the issues you are facing while generating war/ear through maven. You can call ant build.xml using "maven-antrun-plugin", though it will just be a wrapper and you won't be using Maven in true sense